# UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type java.lang.String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I have @Configuration class in lib.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "token")
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
public class JwtTokenSettings {

    @NotBlank
    private String jwtSecret;
    @NotNull
    private Long lifetimeMinutes;
    @NotNull
    private Long refreshTokenLifetimeMinutes;

}
```

and imported sbs-validation in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    ... other dependencies
}
```

my test application.yml

```
token:
  jwt-secret: test
  lifetime-minutes: 1
  refresh-token-lifetime-minutes: 1
```

When i running test to load full context it fails with

```
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'jwtSecret'
```

Why its happen? Another service with that config pass context load test and validators do its work

in another app with this config:

```
token:
  jwt-secret:
  lifetime-minutes: 1
  refresh-token-lifetime-minutes: 1
```

result is:

```
Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'token' to security.jwt.JwtTokenSettings$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4509846 failed:

    Property: token.jwtSecret
    Value: 
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:40:14
    Reason: must not be blank


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

and when i full jwt-secret property test pass

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: 2.3.4 on both apps

Comment: If you get an error the `hibernate-validator` either isn't there or it is the wrong version. So the other app is probably messing around with dependencies somehow.

Comment: i open both jars as archive, both in libs contains same versions of spring-boot-starter-validation and hibernate-validator

Comment: Well not according to your error. Hence you must have something in there that disables validation. However there is too little information in this question.